# The Winterbash 2015 Hatmas "Photo" Album (& maybe embarrassing yearbook)

Tags: discussion, winterbash, winterbash-2015

This album is for **2015**. Check out the 2016 album here: [Hatocalypse 2016 Survivors' Photo Album](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6640/hatocalypse-2016-survivors-photo-album)

---

Every year, there are beautiful fantastic displays with hats and avatars. We see others with avatars we *love*, or we get that perfect dapper combination and enjoy it to bits.

They get boxed up and disappear forever at the end of Winterbash. But they don't have to be! Let's preserve some of it, at least for a while longer. I'd like to try something about that this year.

**So let's have a fun and/or slightly embarrassing yearbook.** Post the great hats and hatments you've seen. Show off the ones *you* made for yourself which you think are fantastic or fabulous or the greatest. (I know I've been there, back with the bowler hat I put on Space Ghost in 2013.) If you spy an excellent thing in the wild, I guess you can stick that here too.

I suggest maybe just one post per person, or at least a very small number. Make edits and expand your post over making new posts.

Keep it silly, keep it fun, and [be nice](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). (Everyone's going to feel self conscious posting anything here, so I suggest we leave criticism at the door.)

---

For those not in the super secret partial screenshot skills club, here's how you do it. First, [here's a magic link to your public profile](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile) that's perfect for screenshotting. Now, the method:

- On Windows 7 and above, you can use the built-in [Snipping Tool](https://superuser.com/a/404279/50208) on your profile page (just hit start and type in the name). Otherwise, you may want to just take a screenshot of your browser window with alt+print screen, paste it into MS Paint, crop out your avatar region and save it as a **PNG**. (GIFs and JPGs will probably come out low quality.)
- On Mac, press CMD + SHIFT + 4 and then click and drag to outline your icon. When you let go of the mouse, it'll save a screenshot .png of the selection to your desktop.
- On Linux... I also have no idea, someone edit this in!

---

For those interested in who has the the most hats here on RPG.SE, the leaderboards can be found [here](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/leaderboard/rpg.stackexchange.com) (as of this posting, Miniman has an astonishing 24 hats).

Comment: I plan to post one, but I am waiting for a specific hat, as some people might already be aware

Comment: I think it's odd to clutter meta with hat questions, so who put the hat on [Community](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)?

Comment: On mac there is keyboard command like Command + Shift + 4 or something, takes you to mode equivalent to snipping tools rectangle snip, and puts image on desktop.

Comment: @HeyICanChan wax eagle put that apropos hat on Community!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Honestly, that privilege sounds like *best* reason to become a moderator. I *am* concerned that Community's *already* earned the Airing of the Grievances hat, though. Community's ability to travel through time is... disconcerting.

Comment: @HeyICanChan To accommodate all timezone residents in the same "day" window to earn a hat, Hatmas "days" are two days long, with the extra day split between before and after UTC. You may begin the Airing of the Grievances!

Comment: I'm tentatively voting to close this as a duplicate of the new one in case that's a good way to roll these forward and avoid year confusion for new posts.

Comment: @doppelgreener I think it'd be more legit to just add a line at the top of this post saying "This is for 2015, check out the 2016 album at [link]."

Comment: @BESW I'm happy with that. :)

Answer (score 22):

### TIMEY-WIMEY DOCTORS

I'm putting a different Doctor in the [Timey Wimey](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/timey-wimey) hat and scarf every day. (Sepia tones are to keep my avatar moderately recognisable despite the rapidly changing images.) Hover over a link to see the Doctor's name and franchise.

[image: "Oh, no, this won't do at all! It's too colourful!"] [image: "So this is my replacement, then? A Bohemian in a Herbert Johnson?"] [image: "Great Scott! This hat is heavy."] [image: "Don't insult my hat. You wouldn't like me if you insult my hat."] [image: "In time I hope you'll allow me my eccentricities, Stack Exchange. Sometimes they're all I or the world have got."]

[image: "This is a hat of very heavy-duty proportions."] [image: "I need this suit tailored! It's an emergency!"] [image: "The great doctors dare to believe in the unbelievable."] [image: "I'm a doctor, not a hatrack!"] [image: "Don't call me Bones."]

[image: "We are in this hat, but perhaps more important is that the hat is in us."] [image: "There, my latest invention."][image: "I'm an archaeologist."] [image: "All questions will be answered in time."] [image: "Not an alien doctor, a proper doctor. A doctor of medicine."]

[image: "But I made him this hat..."] [image: "This is a problem.] [image: "Please explain to me the nature of the hat."] [image: "I do not even know who Tom Baker IS!"] [image: "Not til I'm dead. And sometimes, not even then."]

### [image: "I like my hair."]

Other people are doing the same thing! Here are Doctors I've seen so far. Images link to their user's profile page:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Doctor Eggman would look lovely and cozy in that hat and scarf.

Comment: Alas, he is not the right Doctor

Comment: @trogdor BESW's taking non-DW recommendations too. :)

Comment: ah, my mistake, he did indeed say that XD

Comment: You got a “[*very* honorable mention](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/01/winter-bash-2015-hats-off/)” in the Winter Bash 2015 wrap up blog post!

Answer (score 20):

I started out with [The King of All Cosmos](http://katamari.wikia.com/wiki/The_King_of_All_Cosmos) eating a cake. It's privately amusing to me to no end because it's a really big cake, and one of his catch phrases is "it is too small, it must be bigger, yes." The same goes for him with the christmas tree.

[image: nom nom nom] [image: this tree is too small, it must be bigger, yes]

Over the course of Winter Bash I've also acquired the coveted and fashionable Timey Wimey, and it turns out the King of All Cosmos looks pretty good in it. With his unusually shaped head, *other* hats fit... differently. It's fun.

[image: Timey Wimey: the 4th doctor's hat, hair, and scarf]
[image: Specialist Hatsman: unicorn helmet]
[image: I'm Batman!]
[image: The Airing of Grievances: George Costanza's bald head & glasses]

---

I went back through our chat archives during Winterbash 2013 to see if I'd kept a screenshot of the extremely dapper Space Ghost in his bowler hat, but it looks like I did not. I did have [a lot](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11?m=12731885#12731885) of [fun](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11?m=12734778#12734778) posting about [some](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11?m=12752322#12752322) [other](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11?m=12887353#12887353) [getups](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11?m=12693609#12693609) though.

Comment: I see you have temporarily gone back to batman. Batman, King of All Cosmos, in fact.

Comment: @MrLemon I was actually [Space Ghost](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KFsDU.jpg) before! But the King of All Cosmos is always on the side of justice! (And on the side of indulging in extravagant outfits.)

Answer (score 12):

I have a cat with food on its face, as [is traditional on the Internet](http://25.media.tumblr.com/583f5ffb1ae208adb09745d87b6caa89/tumblr_mm8knqg2DY1qgvkddo1_400.gif):

[image: Sufganiyot hat on nose]

Also, [hurr durr I'm a dog](https://i.imgur.com/3gqZYSX.jpg):

[image: Researcher hat]

And because you can find [anything](http://media2.popsugar-assets.com/files/2014/10/29/988/n/1922507/1dbc7e25a38663dc_1956723_10152762693172488_4021531078553772624_o/i/Thor-Cat.jpg) on the Interwebs:

[image: Odinson hat]

Comment: Congratulations on the very shiny golden hat! I like the catdog & nose-food. The cake stayed there quite a while without getting eaten!

Comment: @doppelgreener I want to add a [Batman](http://www.syzm.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/funny-cat-cone-head-Batman.jpg) one but I haven't gotten that hat yet.

Comment: nice, that third one is really great XD

Comment: [mashes upvote button harder]

Answer (score 10):

Surely, not one of the greatest that got posted here, but I am very proud of this dapper beguiler I created.

[image: A very dapper beguiler]

And I noticed the harbinger also decided to preach and eat *in style*. Classy, eimyr.

[image: A very dapper C'thulhu]

Comment: I am thoroughly beguiled by how dapper it is.

Answer (score 8):

I got [Cerro de Potosi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potos%C3%AD) as a hat and it makes sense as headwear for Cthulhu. I probably won't change avatar just for the sake of having a different hat, as Elder Gods do not face rejection kindly.

[image: I AWAKEN]

Understandably, even the mighty Cthulhu falls prey to the irresistible pull of [cromniomancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cromniomancy).

[image: I AM ETERNAL]

Comment: Do you think they know they're on top of an elder god?

Comment: @doppelgreener Aren't we all?

Answer (score 8):

I fear that I am about 1½ months late, but here's my dancing cactus cowboy dressed up as a Ghost.

[image]

Comment: That's an excellent improvised ghost costume. Very spook, wow.

Comment: I would never have thought to do this XD. very creative

Answer (score 7):

[image] and finally this one, I think it requires little explanation why I like this one

this one is pretty neat, it isn't the one I have been waiting for, but it tickles me enough to post it in the meantime

[image]

now for what I was waiting to post here, not sure it ended up as awesome as I wanted, mainly it would have been better if there was an opening for the face to show through
[image]

maybe it's better like this?
[image]

Comment: So now I have Pinkie Pie in my mind force-choking people who aren't partying hard enough, and convincing her errant daughter to join her in together restoring wild parties to the galaxy.

Comment: I can totally see that happening, though it seems kinda like a cake or die situation

Answer (score 6):

I am loathe to find a hat that would be better than this:

[image]

[image]

How about now? This white and gold hat is driving my mad.

Comment: If it looks off, consider that the lower black rim will show where the hat's inner rim is lying against the dog's head. Maybe tuck it in closer against the side of his head? Close enough is close enough though. Is that a parody of the dogs playing poker painting?

Comment: It looks like that! Thanks for pointing it out, it did send me with some intermediate steps towards this [GeekList](https://boardgamegeek.com/geeklist/160271/depictions-tabletop-role-playing/page/1?), which I didn't know I was missing until now.

Comment: @doppelgreener Why, yes, yes it is. Hmm... I'll try to see what I can do about the skewing just right.

Answer (score 5):

In response to all the "Jar Jar Binks is a Sith" theories that have been circling the internet prior to the premiere, I present to you an alternative: Darth [Zoidberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoidberg) (in Android form).

[image: They said the Dark Side had cookies...]

*Poor Zoidberg was crushed when he realized that, in fact, the Dark Side does not have cookies.*

Comment: Perhaps he'd have more luck [staring into the abyss](http://ursulav.deviantart.com/art/The-Abyss-Looks-Back-62380479).

Answer (score 5):

This might not be good enough, and if it isn't feel free to smite it with your meta-privileges, but I find this Oracle to be particularly Crisp and Smooth.

[image: Wow!]

When I got this hat, I immediately put it on, and then I sat and appreciated this image for a good 5 minutes before I decided to be a more productive being (after passing a wisdom save).

Answer (score 4):

So far I've just got sad Eddie, Eddie-in-disguise, and Eddie-to-the-nines. Presumably he's on the way to a benefit/gala.

(Anything else interferes too much with his beautiful, beautiful, big 80's hair.)

[image: sad Eddie]
[image: incognito Eddie]
[image: Eddie to the nines]

For the after-party, Eddie takes some fashion tips from Mark Knopfler:
[image: Eddie and the 'band]

Comment: I love the Do You Even Lift headband. Very 80's.

Comment: @doppelgreener It's also the only hat that works well on an avatar that's in profile rather than head-on! *#it'scoincidentalthatIknowthis*

Answer (score 4):

Is it a [controversial royal celebrity hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214536/can-we-have-a-royal-hat-next-year)…

[image: The Fan-hat-ic hat upright, as it was meant to be worn]

… or is it a <strike>horrifying</strike> charming cephalopod* lovingly sitting upon your head?

[image: Fan-hat-it hat worn upside down looks like an octopus]

I think the correct answer is clear.

<sup>* “But it only has four legs!” Obviously the other four tentacles are behind your head, for stability. You wouldn't want *widdle pwecious wookums* to fall off, would you?</sup>

Comment: [I vote charming cephalopod](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iu9c3.png)