# 2020 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

Role-playing Games's [fifth moderator election](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election/5) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied and the two new moderators are:

[image: Someone_Evil] [image: linksassin]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly—please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

Also, please join me in thanking [nitsua60](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9875/to-every-thing-there-is-a-season) and [doppelgreener](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9915/in-which-a-doppelgreener-becomes-somewhat-less-shiny), who will be stepping down as moderators.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/election/5), or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5340814077067264/0).

Comment: Let me start by thanking everyone who voted and put your faith in us, and to Ben for running. It would, unfortunately, not be much of an election if someone didn't lose.

Comment: Congratulations to both of you, and thank you as well to Ben for putting your hand up beside them.

Comment: Congratulations you two! :) I've consistently appreciated your input to the stack - really happy you got voted in. **senmurv happy dance**

Answer (score 12):

### Congrats, and thanks to everyone who ran!

Someone_Evil and linksassin, I look forward to having you on the team. Ben, you were a great candidate too - don't be too discouraged by the results, and I hope you run again in future elections. You were all excellent candidates. I'm excited to see what you bring to the moderator team!

Comment: Ditto all this.

Answer (score 9):

## Thanks for the opportunity

It was a privilege to get to run in this election and an honor to be selected. I hope I can live up to the faith the community has placed in me, as well as the legacy of the terrific mods who have come before me.

Comment: I have faith in you.  Thanks for tossing your  hat into the ring.

Comment: I'm still stunned by the mid-election revelation that your username isn't "LinkAssassin."  A scandal like that could have derailed your whole candidacy....

Comment: @Novak Maybe it was my real name but I had to hide my identity? We'll never know.

Comment: Or it could be I need reading glasses, but haven't had time to get them.

Comment: For the last three years.

Answer (score 8):

### We had no way to lose

Two good choices, and a third who'd have been good also.
As I said in chat:
[You Look Good in Blue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxmNdVC02Qg)

Champagne all around.  Doppelgreener's buying. *evil grin*
(KS sneaks out the back of the tavern)